# How to pass parameter value to aspect

Tags: spring-aop, aspect

How do we get the parameter value(uId) from calling method(deleteTask) of JointPoint(in logJdbcOperation)? I am able to log sql statement and sql parameters but cannot find a way to log value of uId.
Please, guide me.

```java
public int deleteTask(String taskname, String uId) {
        String sql = "delete from shedlock where NAME= :name";
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        ((MapSqlParameterSource) namedParameters).addValue("name", taskname, Types.VARCHAR);
        return namedJdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameters);
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core..NamedParameterJdbcOperations.*(String, ..))")
    public void logJdbcOperation(JoinPoint jp) {
        Object[] methodArgs = jp.getArgs();
        String statement = methodArgs[0].toString();
        MapSqlParameterSource params = (MapSqlParameterSource)methodArgs[1];
        LOGGER.debug("SQL statement:" + statement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code shared does not show how the `uId` is passed on to the method `namedJdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameters)`. It is not possible to get the parameter to the calling method . Any parameter of the target method can be obtained.

Following code would advice the method `deleteTask` and get the arguments passed to it.

```java
@Around("execution(* package.deleteTask(..)) && args(taskName,uId)")
public Object logDeleteTask(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String taskName, String uId) {
  LOGGER.debug("Task Name :" + taskName);
  LOGGER.debug("Uid :" + uId);
  Object ret = 0;
  try {
    ret = pjp.proceed();
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    // handle exception if any
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Reference : [Passing Parameter to Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing)

Note : Remember to modify the `package.deleteTask(..)` to approrpriate package name.

Comment: Kriegaex, thanks for your answer. yes, uId is not passed to namedJdbcTemplete.update as it's not needed. but for the log, i need to have uId, sql, and namedParameters at the same time. For your logDeleteTask, it does not give sql and namedparameters. like you said it seems it's not possible. I am thinking of creating a new method to wrap the namedJdbcTemplate.update to pass uId and use that method in aspect. which I don't really like to do that as I need to change original codes just for logging :( I hope I can find a better way to handle this...